# Length metrics on covering spaces

Tags: gn.general-topology, mg.metric-geometry, covering-spaces

This is a question (Exercise 3.30(2)) in the book `Metric spaces of non-positive curvature' written by Bridson and Haefliger.

In the book, there is the following proposition (Proposition 3.28)

Let $p:\tilde{X}\rightarrow X$ be a map of length spaces such that
(1) $X$ is connected,
(2) $p$ is a local homeomorphism
(3) the length of every path in $\tilde{X}$ is not bigger than the length of its image under $p$,
(4) $X$ is locally uniquely geodesic and geodesics in $X$ vary continuously with their endpoints locally, and
(5) $\tilde{X}$ is complete.
Then, $p$ is a covering map.

The authors said that the continuity requirement in condition (4) is necessary, even for locally contractible spaces.
But I couldn't find an example showing the reason why the requirement should be needed.
If you have an idea, I wish you share it.

Thank you.

Comment: I cannot find an example of locally contractible spaces, and I do not see how that example mentioned by Bridson and Haefliger might help here. But an example with unique geodesics can be constructed as here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/990389/ --- one has to exchange each circle with a "fan" a point that is connected to each point of a short interval by a longer line segment of fixed size.